# Add custom attributes as dropdown in list.phtml page

Tags: php, iphone, magento, attributes

I am using a third party magento extension (IPhone theme). So this theme is not displaying my custom attributes for example "year,brand.." in my IPhone. But those attributes are showing fine in the Desktop with their dropdown so you can filter.
There is a file "list.phtml" for this plugin theme and I want to add my custom attributes with their dropdown so user can filter out the result in their IPhone theme.
I am trying to put this code but it is just showing an empty select box. Please help

```
 $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
 $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

<select id='filter' onchange="ajaxfunction()">
<?php foreach($_productCollection as $product): ?>
<option value="<?php $product->getAttributeText('years') ?>"><?php     $product->getAttributeText('years') ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: `echo $product->getAttributeText('years');`

Comment: oopss.. how did i miss it.. how to put link on it <a href="<what code to put>"><?php echo $product->getAttributeText('years') ?></a>

Comment: You would echo the url in the same way. `<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">...`

Comment: so lets say the actual link should be www.test.com/page.phtml?years=125. so how would i add the attribute type and attribute ID. $url is giving me the path but i need to add querystring with attribute type and ID